# Swift view appears to delay being loaded into window hierarchy

Tags: swift, xcode

A very strange thing is happening, it appears my initial view controller loads up, performs its logic and all but the actual view itself isn't added to the hierarchy until everything else happens.

```
    protocol OnboardDisplayLogic: class
{
    func handleUserConfirmation(viewModel: OnboardModels.CheckForUser.ViewModel)
}

class OnboardViewController: UIViewController, OnboardDisplayLogic {

    var interactor: OnboardInteractor?
    var router: (NSObjectProtocol & OnboardRoutingLogic & OnboardDataPassing)?

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    //MARK: Setup

    private func setup() {
        let viewController = self
        let interactor = OnboardInteractor()
        let presenter = OnboardPresenter()
        let router = OnboardRouter()
        viewController.interactor = interactor
        viewController.router = router
        interactor.presenter = presenter
        presenter.viewController = viewController
        router.viewController = viewController
        router.dataStore = interactor
    }

    private func setupView() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    }

    //MARK: Routing

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let scene = segue.identifier {
            let selector = NSSelectorFromString("routeTo\(scene)WithSegue:")
            if let router = router, router.responds(to: selector) {
                router.perform(selector, with: segue)
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: View lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupView()
        interactor?.checkForUser()
    }

    func handleUserConfirmation(viewModel: OnboardModels.CheckForUser.ViewModel) {
        if let username = viewModel.username {
            print("Logged in user: \(username)")
            router?.routeToUserFeed(segue: nil)
        } else {
            print("No user logged in")
            router?.routeToLoginRegister(segue: nil)
        }
    }
```

The reason I think it's delayed is that although I've set the view background colour to brown, using breakpoints at the `print("user not logged in")` code I get that printed to console, because there is no user logged in as determined the Interactor, but view remains white.  It's not until I step over and complete running all the code does the screen then become brown.

Therefore I'm getting the error

> Warning: Attempt to present ... whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

as something is preventing the view from being added until the very end.

Comment: Where you call setupView()?

Comment: In viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual views aren't loaded until they enter the view controller lifecycle.
If you need to load the view to setup before it's added to a superview's hierarchy, just use the getter of the view (`let _ = viewController.view`).

`UIViewController`s also have the `loadView()` method, check it out: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview).

We've also had these kind of problems with Clean Swift. The correct way of working would be to instantiate from the storyboard and just use normal segues/lifecycle, just as MVC does for Apple examples.

Instead of doing `let viewControllerToPush = MyVCSublass(...)`, you should instantiate from storyboard `let viewControllerToPush = storyboard?.instantiate...` and use that view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm not quite understanding though, I thought that since I put my function calls in viewDidLoad, that meant the view should already be loaded and accessible at that time?  The other issue is all my coding is programmatic so I don't use storyboards.  I'm still not clear as to why my call to present a new VC from OnboardViewController from inside viewDidLoad doesn't work.

Comment: @TinLuong I get it. How are you presenting this particular view controller? Is it a `pushViewController(_:)`? The easiest way to solve a view not loaded is to add a `loadView()` at the end of your `setup()` method.

Comment: @TinLuong and to complement, are you trying to *present* a new view controller over the current one on `viewDidLoad`? That won't work, since the `view` is instantiated and loaded, but *not* added to a view hierarchy. You should do that after a view has appeared (ehem... `viewDidAppear`).

Comment: The OnboardViewController is the very first one, so its instantiated in appdelegate, window = rootViewController(OnboardViewController())

Comment: @TinLuong and, when `OnboardViewController` appears on screen, you want to push a new view controller on top of it?

Comment: By the way, thanks using viewDidAppear of course fixed the issue.  It's very strange because this issue has never happened before.  Is it because of the way Clean Swift works?  Using viewDidLoad always worked even when presenting subsequent VC's.

Comment: @TinLuong it's the way view controllers work. That a view controller has a view loaded doesn't mean it's on screen, it just means that: it's loaded into memory. After that, other methods (like `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidAppear`) will be called too. Only on `viewDidAppear` you can be sure your view is on screen (and only there you can present new view controllers using push/present). When a view is loaded, you can *add subviews* directly, but not present/push in a view controller style.

Comment: Check out Apple documentation about view controllers and their lifecycles: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html